# GPO installed network printers wont show up under user account but only admin login

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

I use GPO to push out a network printer per machine from server 2008. but it only shows up under admin account.

I restarted the PC , login logoff , gpupdate /force.... then it still only shows up on admin login....

any idea why?

I followed the instruction here to do it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722179(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Could you add some details and/or a screenshot about how you have our GPO set up?  Gonna be nothing but guesswork until you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is heck of an old article. I think you are better off trying this with Group Policy Extensions:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731562.aspx

> Computer Configuration or User Configuration
>
> └ Preferences
>
> ```
>   └ Control Panel Settings 
>
>      └ Printers
> ```

Comment: Yeah, It works this way even it says apply to 2008r2, but on 2008 works too. Thanks